# Aligning multiple places in equations using align

Tags: equations, align

My question is simple. I've played around with the `&` symbol to align my equations neatly under each other, but I just can't get it to look nice. This is the closest I've got:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A_{0} & = -\frac{3\sigma_{1}' h H L^{2}}{E (H+h)^{3}} &=& -1.62\times 10^{-6}\,\mathrm{m} \\
B_{0} & = - \frac{3 h H (\alpha_{2}-\alpha_{1}) L^{2}}{(H+h)^{3}} &=&  2.95\times 10^{-8}\,\mathrm{m\,K^{-1}} \\
C_{0} & = \frac{4 L^{3}}{E W (H+h)^{3}} &=& 1.08\,\mathrm{m\,N^{-1}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:
[image]

How can I **remove the horizontal space** in the middle yet still align the equal signs under each other? It should be the middle equation that dictates the spaces, i.e. the other two equations need to align to that one.

As a final question I could ask: How would *you* do it to make it 'look nice'?

And yes, I have looked at the other similar questions without luck.

Comment: And also, strangely there is no/very little space after the right equal sign - why?

Comment: none of the answers has addressed the question in your comment, about the lack of space after the second `=` sign.  in order to get the correct space, (la)tex has to consider the classes of the two adjacent characters.  since the second `=` is followed by a `&`, there isn't any character there to check, and *no* space is left.  you can force it by adding `{}` after the `=`, but it's better to simply put both `&&` *before* the `=`.  (or follow the guidance of the "real" answers.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Two solutions with `alignat`; one of them has two alignment points, the other, three, so that the numeric values are aligned on the integer part of the mantissa:

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
A_{0} & = -\frac{3σ_{1}' h H L²}{E (H+h)³} &&= - & & 1.62 × 10⁻⁶\,\mathrm{m} \\
B_{0} & = - \frac{3 h H (α_{2}-α_{1}) L²}{(H+h)³} &&= & & 2.95 × 10⁻⁸\,\mathrm{m\,K⁻¹} \\
C_{0} & = \frac{4 L³}{E W (H+h)³} &&= & & 1.08\,\mathrm{m\,N⁻¹}
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{2}
A_{0} & = -\frac{3σ_{1}' h H L²}{E (H+h)³} &&= - 1.62 × 10⁻⁶\,\mathrm{m} \\
B_{0} & = - \frac{3 h H (α_{2}-α_{1}) L²}{(H+h)³} &&= 2.95 × 10⁻⁸\,\mathrm{m\,K⁻¹} \\
C_{0} & = \frac{4 L³}{E W (H+h)³} &&= 1.08\,\mathrm{m\,N⁻¹}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your top answer is exactly what I was looking for! It's nice to have the numeric values aligned as well.

Answer (score 10):

What you need is `alignat`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
A_{0} & = -\frac{3\sigma_{1}' h H L^{2}}{E (H+h)^{3}} &{}={}& -1.62\times 10^{-6}\,\mathrm{m} \\
B_{0} & = - \frac{3 h H (\alpha_{2}-\alpha_{1}) L^{2}}{(H+h)^{3}} &{}={}&  2.95\times 10^{-8}\,\mathrm{m\,K^{-1}} \\
C_{0} & = \frac{4 L^{3}}{E W (H+h)^{3}} &{}={}& 1.08\,\mathrm{m\,N^{-1}}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

`\begin{alignat}{2}` aligns at two points (two equation columns) and you have to use three `&`s. To get the proper spacing around `=` in the second column use `{}={}`

[image]

Comment: Kudos for the `{} = {}`. Without it the spacing is really weird.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the `alignat` environment. Also, use [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) for the physical quantities.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  A_{0}
  &= -\frac{3\sigma_{1}'hHL^{2}}{E(H+h)^{3}}
  &&= \SI{-1.62e-6}{\m} \\
  B_{0}
  &= - \frac{3hH(\alpha_{2}-\alpha_{1})L^{2}}{(H+h)^{3}}
  &&= \SI{2.95e-8}{\m\per\K} \\
  C_{0}
  &= \frac{4L^{3}}{EW(H+h)^{3}}
  &&= \SI{1.08}{\m\per\N}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

**Update**

Inspired by [Barnard's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203563/15874), here is a way in case you also want to align the units:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{4}
  A_{0}
  &= -\frac{3\sigma_{1}'hHL^{2}}{E(H+h)^{3}}
  &&={}& -1.62 &\times 10^{-6} && \,\si{\m} \\
  B_{0}
  &= - \frac{3hH(\alpha_{2}-\alpha_{1})L^{2}}{(H+h)^{3}}
  &&={}& 2.95 &\times 10^{-8} && \,\si{\m\per\K} \\
  C_{0}
  &= \frac{4L^{3}}{EW(H+h)^{3}}
  &&={}& 1.08 & && \,\si{\m\per\N}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Comment: @CarstenGade You're welcome. Side-note: In case you have table tables with physical quantities, `siunitx` is again the way to go when typesetting them (see the manual)!

Comment: Hm, apparently I can only accept one answer. I will accept Bernard's since he also aligned the numeric values, which is nice.

Comment: @CarstenGade No problem. If you had told me about your other alignment request, I could have done that for you as well. `:)`

Comment: @Svend Tveskæg: Good point for the siunitx loading that I had forgotten.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I don't doubt it ;) It's nice to see a fellow dane in here, btw.

Comment: @CarstenGade Nice to see you too. `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I tried compiling your code, but it comes up with an error: "LaTeX Error: File `expl3.sty' not found." I have installed the siunitx package, but I can't find expl3 through MikTeX's Package Manager - what to do?

Comment: @CarstenGade Do you have an up-to-date distribution? I use TeX Live myself so I'm not sure how to fix it if it's a version problem.